# Javascript syntax error caused by regex - specific to Internet Explorer(all versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a web application I ported from a Cordova project which works without problems on all common browsers except for IE. So far I have tested this application in Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, Safari and Edge.

The problem in Internet Explorer returns an error saying that "'submit' is undefined" whenever the following line is added to the code.

```
usr_id = /\[usr_id\] => (.*?)\n/gum.exec(response);
```

My guess is that the escape characters are somehow breaking the syntax but playing around with that didn't solve my problem.

The offending part in context below:

```
    function submit(){
        uname = $('#txt-uname').val();
        password = $('#txt-password').val();
        login(uname,password);
    }

    function login(tc,pass){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  webserviceURL+'login.php',
            data: {'tc':tc, 'password':pass},
            complete: function(r){
                response = r.responseText;

                if (response.indexOf("") > -1){
                    localStorage.setItem("login", "true");

                    usr_id = /\[usr_id\] => (.*?)\n/gum.exec(response);
                    localStorage.setItem("usr_id", 'test');

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll change much, but you should definitely define your variables with the `var` keyword to avoid using global vars everywhere.

Comment: do you see an error in the console? "Error in regular expression" perhaps? ... it's the `u` in `gum` that IE doesn't like

Comment: the variables are declared elsewhere in the code but I simplified it to highlight the problem. thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Does your version of IE support the `u` Unicode flag? It's a relatively new addition, and IE doesn't get updates nearly as frequently as other browsers. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex

Comment: no version of IE supprts the `u` flag - in fact only very recent chrum and firfox do

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeBunny, I'm curious why you added the `u` flag in the first place. Was it intentional?

Comment: @DanWilson I just happened to have added it when testing the regex in regex101. When moving the regex to the application I left it there not thinking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have `u` as the unicode flag in Internet Explorer. It is not supported yet. Please change your RegEx to:

```
usr_id = /\[usr_id\] => (.*?)\n/gm.exec(response);
```

Also, you can check the support by checking the response of:

```
RegExp.prototype.unicode
```

And if it supported for the browsers, use the `u` flag, as it breaks your original logic without that. With this change, at least, it works in Internet Explorer gracefully. This can be checked using:

```
(new RegExp()).unicode
```

It might return `undefined` in Internet Explorer, while `false` in other browsers.

Comment: Unicode flag was not really necessary, I just threw it in there for good measure. The code works as intended now. 

If I needed to do a regex search with unicode would there be a workaround?

Comment: @CodeBunny Nothing I know of in Internet Explorer. You need to drop the support of that application, as it is not even a browser. LoL. This "not browser" thing holds good for Safari now-a-days, in Mac. (Safari is the new Internet Explorer for Mac). LoL.

Comment: @CodeBunny Workaround: Use a unicode plugin: http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Comment: I agree that IE is not even a browser, but at least it's dead! We just have wait until earth reclaims the rotting carcass. 

Never had a bad experience in Safari (not supporting my code kind of bad experience)

Comment: @CodeBunny Safari does have a huge number of issues, despite it uses WebKit.