# Syntax error in my phone regular expression (Internet Explorer 11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

my regular is:

```
var phoneRegExp = new RegExp('^(370[0-9]{8}|371[0-9]{8}|372[0-9]{8,9}|373[0-9]{8}|374[0-9]{8}|375[0-9]{9}|380[0-9]{9}|992[0-9]{9}|993[0-9]{8}|994[0-9]{9}|995[0-9]{9}|996[0-9]{8,9}|998[0-9]{9}|77[0-9]{9,10}|7[0-9]{10})$', 'gu');
```

IE11 in win 8.1 return an error "syntax error in regular expression", but regulear is very simple...

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can debug your regex with https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you try it in a different Browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353495/javascript-syntax-error-caused-by-regex-specific-to-internet-explorerall-vers

Comment: @JosefWittmann thanks! problem was with flag "u" for ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with flag "u", in my case for numbers i can don't use it